# 2 Boxes inside a box in CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like some one to provide me with a valid css which can put 2 Boxes inside a box.
like in the image I have given

[image: This is what I want it to look like]
**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
            #adbox {
                width: 602px;
                height: 250px;
                border-width: 0;
                border-color: red;
            }
            #adbox .adbox1 {
                width: 300px;
                height: 250px;
                border-width: 0;
                border-color: red;
                }
            #adbox .adbox2 {
                width: 300px;
                height: 250px;
                border-width: 0;
                border-color: red;
        }
    </style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div align=center><div id="adbox">
<div class="adbox1">
<img src="foobar1.jpg" border="0" />
</div>
<div class="adbox2">
<img src="foobar.jpg" border="0" />
</div>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you want to align the boxes like in the image you provided.

You can do this with this css:

```
#adbox {
  width: 600px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px red solid;
}

#adbox .adbox1, #adbox .adbox2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  float: left;
  outline: 1px red solid;
}
```

Example: http://tinkerbin.com/5MAX3Mt2

Answer (score 1):

Well..You didn't ask the question....I am assuming that you want to place the two boxes side by side and I am providing answer based on my assumption. Change your html and css as below if you want to place the two boxes side by side

Also note the usage of "clear" class which clears the floats

html

```
<div align=center><div id="adbox"> 
<div class="adbox1"> 
<img src="foobar1.jpg" border="0" /> 
</div> 
<div class="adbox2"> 
<img src="foobar.jpg" border="0" /> 
</div> 
<div class="clear"/>
</div></div>
```

CSS

```
#adbox {   
            width: 602px;   
            height: 250px;   
            border-width: 0;   
            border-color: red;   
        }   
        #adbox .adbox1 {   
            width: 300px;   
            height: 250px;   
            border-width: 0;   
            border-color: red;  
            float:left; 
            }   
        #adbox .adbox2 {   
            width: 300px;   
            height: 250px;   
            border-width: 0;   
            border-color: red;   
            float:left;
    }   
    .clear{
         clear:both;
    }
```